# JSONDecoder().decode fails when commas

Tags: json, swift, decoder

JSONDecoder().decode fails when there are commas at the end of a name field. Why is it happening? How can I solve it?

```
    let string = "[{\"name\":\"Homeoffice Marc,\",\"Km\":846.7911330652549,\"Strid\": \"DE262B62633E34AAA8A622E189B42920B319C371\"},{\"name\":\"Küche,\",\"Km\":857.8694764184313,\"Strid\": \"BD1A60D736BE86377121A2CC713251DBE2603BD5\"},{\"name\":\"Besprechungszimmer,\",\"Km\":857.8721480885644,\"Strid\": \"751A10C5D3065F91CC9F5BDF5E7111DC452D1C39\"},{\"name\":\"Büro Vertrieb,\",\"Km\":857.8723091979339,\"Strid\": \"148F97F324BB59EAFF613A0EB3766E026CFAB320\"},{\"name\":\"Büro Produktmanagement und Support,\",\"Km\":857.8734889037903,\"Strid\": \"3A37C955F7D3C012577B1D19B6F662AD233372A5\"},{\"name\":\"Tischkicker,\",\"Km\":857.8748603133218,\"Strid\": \"B5B8A86BBA2102AF56721166D2E814736EF13132\"},{\"name\":\"Büro Entwicklung,\",\"Km\":857.8773683652697,\"Strid\": \"E6814BE03EEF386E63AD7609D970BD9BA8CE71AD\"},{\"name\":\"Syfit GmbH,\",\"Km\":857.877841443768,\"Strid\": \"64F80B1EC04D008E060F28D7F198A8C39DCD53B5\"},{\"name\":\"Büro Zolti,\",\"Km\":857.8798725612223,\"Strid\": \"23F4C2E1C467AEC9D55D873DC3ED7FC73CD92177\"},{\"name\":\"Globale Suche\",\"Km\":null,\"Km\":846.7911330652549}]"
    
let data = string.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
let areas = try? JSONDecoder().decode([AreaModel].self, from: data)
```

decoding this data returns nil

My model:

```
struct AreaModel: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case km = "Km"
        case strid = "Strid"
    }
    
    let name: String
    let km: Double?
    let strid: String
}
```

Comment: please share all code

Comment: I added all code. Please take a look. Want to add that without trailing commas in name everything decoding as expected

Comment: Did you notice that the last entry has a duplicate key "Km"?

Comment: may be it's a typo or logical error check it `let strid: String?`

Comment: Use a proper do/try/catch and print the error, that should reveal the problem quickly.

Comment: Wow actually I haven't. Our backend team said that the problem appeared when they add commas, so I didn't expect to see problem in other place. Thank you a lot. I really wasted a lot of time on this issue.

Comment: Another debugging option is to validate  the JSON, e.g.  at https://jsonlint.com. It will tell you "Error: Duplicate key 'Km'". Give that info to your backend team.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't ignore thrown errors.

If you can't debug yourself, **NEVER USE** `try?`. With more experience, I'd say that we tend to not use `try?`, but sometimes we do. But when we write `try?`, we are able to find an possible issue, ie debug if needed.

Let's do a proper try then, with a do/catch:

```
do {
    let areas = try JSONDecoder().decode([AreaModel].self, from: data)
    print(areas)
} catch {
    print("Error while decoding: \(error)") //and print error, not error.description which is for non-developer and will be missing important information
}
```

Which should output:

```
Error while decoding: 
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Strid", intValue: nil),
                       Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 9", intValue: 9)], 
                       debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Strid\", intValue: nil) (\"Strid\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

So, it's the 9th element of your JSON array that causes the issue.
It can't decode properly `Strid` value. There is no valid String value.

Let's see... You have `{"name":"Globale Suche","Km":null,"Km":846.7911330652549}`. In fact you have no `Strid` key here. Did you meant `{"name":"Globale Suche","Strid":null,"Km":846.7911330652549}`? Even if that's the case it's `null`, in other words, in Swift it would be `nil`. So to handle that case, you need to make `Strid` value optional

```
let strid: String?
```

Side note, the start of the answer if taken for [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69002191/1801544), so clearly not plagiarism.